# My program won't sort arrays that are larger than 130

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

So my program is supposed to take in user input (an integer between 10 and 200) and print out an array of random numbers and print out a sorted version of that array. However, this only works when I enter in 130 or less.

I don't know what else I can do. It works but only half way. Is there any way to optimize this code? I have placed lines to help show which procedure I am having problems with.

****I ran debugger and I have left a comment where the program throws an exception error.*****

```
TITLE Program5    (Program5.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

; (insert constant definitions here)
    MIN_INPUT = 10
    MAX_INPUT = 200
    LO_RANDOM = 100
    HI_RANDOM = 999

.data

; (insert variable definitions here)
intro           BYTE    "Fun with Arrays! by ", 0
instruction     BYTE    "This program generates random numbers in the range [100 .. 999], displays the original list, sorts the list, and calculates the median value. Finally, it displays the list sorted in descending order", 0

request         DWORD   10
ask_user        BYTE    "How many numbers should be generated? [10 ... 200]: ", 0
error           BYTE    "Invalid input", 0

title_1         BYTE    "The unsorted random numbers: ", 0
title_2         BYTE    "The sorted list: ", 0
space           BYTE    "   ", 0

mult            DWORD   0.5

temp            DWORD   0

list            DWORD   MAX_INPUT   DUP(?)

.code
main PROC

; (insert executable instructions here)
    call    randomize
    call    introduction

    push    OFFSET request ;passed by reference
    call    getData

    call    CrLf

    push    request ; passed by value
    push    OFFSET list ; passed by reference
    call    fillArray

    push    OFFSET list
    push    request
    push    OFFSET title_1
    call    displaylist

    call    CrLf

    push    OFFSET list
    push    request
    call    sortList

    call    CrLf
;
    push    OFFSET list
    push    request
    push    OFFSET title_2
    call    displaylist

    ;push   OFFSET list
    ;push   request
    ;call   displayMedian

    exit    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

; (insert additional procedures here)
introduction PROC

    mov     edx, OFFSET intro
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    mov     edx, OFFSET instruction
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf
    ret 

introduction ENDP

getData PROC
;include parameter - request (reference)

    push    ebp ;Set up stack frame
    mov     ebp, esp

    ;get an integer from user
    mov     ebx, [ebp+8]    ;get address of request into ebx

    L1:
        mov     edx, OFFSET ask_user
        call    WriteString
        call    ReadDec

        cmp     eax, MIN_INPUT
        jl      errorMessage
        cmp     eax, MAX_INPUT
        jg      errorMessage

        cmp     eax, MIN_INPUT
        jge     endThis
        cmp     eax, MAX_INPUT
        jle     endThis

    errorMessage:
        mov     edx, OFFSET error
        call    WriteString
        call    CrLf
        jmp     L1

    endThis:
        mov     [ebx], eax
        pop     ebp
        ret     4 ; remove four more bytes from the stack (after ret @)
getData ENDP

fillArray PROC
;include parameters - request (value), array (reference)
    ; MAJORITY OF THE FOLLOWING CODE WAS EXTRACTED FROM LECTURE 20 SLIDES
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp ;[ebp+4]
    mov     edi, [ebp+8] ; @list in edi
    mov     ecx, [ebp+12] ; value of request in ecx

    more:
        mov     eax, HI_RANDOM
        sub     eax, LO_RANDOM
        inc     eax
        call    RandomRange
        add     eax, LO_RANDOM

        mov     [edi], eax
        add     edi, 4
        loop    more

    endmore:
        pop     ebp
        ret     8
fillArray ENDP

;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sortList PROC
;include parameters - array (reference), request (value)
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp ;[ebp+4]
    mov     edi, [ebp+12] ; @list in edi
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8] ; value of request in ecx

    dec     ecx ; request - 1
    mov     ebx, 0 ; "k"

    ;for(k=0; k<request-1; k++) { 
       ;i = k; 
       ;for(j=k+1; j<request; j++) { 
          ;if(array[j] > array[i]) 
             ;i = j; 
       ;} 
       ;exchange(array[k], array[i]); 
    ;} 

    firstLoop:
        mov     eax, ebx ; "i = k"

        mov     edx, ebx ; "j = k"
        inc     edx ; "j = k + 1"
        push    ecx ; pushed the first loop's counter
        mov     ecx, [ebp+8] ; made the second loop's counter = request

        secondLoop:
            mov     esi, [edi + (edx * 4)] ; array[j] ; EXCEPTION WAS THROWN HERE
            cmp     esi, [edi + (eax * 4)] ; compare array[j] and array[i]
            jg      greater
            jle     lesser

            greater:
                mov     eax, edx
                inc     edx
                loop    secondLoop

            lesser:
                inc     edx
                loop    secondLoop

        push    edx
        push    esi
        push    [edi + (ebx * 4)] ; array[k]
        push    [edi + (eax * 4)] ; array[i]
        call    exchangeElements
        pop     [edi + (eax * 4)]
        pop     [edi + (ebx * 4)]
        pop     esi
        pop     edx
        pop     ecx ; set the 
        inc     ebx ; increment k in the first loop
        loop    firstLoop

    pop     ebp
    ret     8

sortList ENDP

exchangeElements PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov     esi, [ebp+12] ; array[k]
    mov     edx, [ebp+8] ; array[i]
    mov     [ebp+8], esi
    mov     [ebp+12], edx
    pop     ebp
    ret     
exchangeElements ENDP
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------

displayMedian PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp ;[ebp+4]
    mov     edi, [ebp+12] ; @list in edi
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8] ; value of request in ecx

    mov     eax, ecx
    mov     ebx, 2
    cdq
    div     ebx
    cmp     edx, 0
    je      isEven
    cmp     edx, 1
    je      isOdd

            ;def nlogn_median(l):
    ;l = sorted(l)
    ;if len(l) % 2 == 1:
        ;return l[len(l) / 2]
    ;else:
        ;return 0.5 * (l[len(l) / 2 - 1] + l[len(l) / 2])

    isEven:
        mov     esi, [edi + (eax - 1)]
        add     esi, [edi + (eax)]
        mov     eax, esi
        mov     ebx, 2
        cdq
        div     ebx
        call    WriteDec

    isOdd:
        mov     eax, [edi + (eax*4)]
        call    WriteDec

    pop ebp
    ret
displayMedian ENDP

displayList PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp ; [ebp+4]
    mov     ecx, [ebp+12] ; @request
    mov     edi, [ebp+16] ; @list
    mov     esi, 10

    mov     edx, [ebp+8] ; @title
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf

    show:
        mov     eax, [edi]
        call    WriteDec
        mov     edx, OFFSET space
        call    WriteString
        add     edi, 4

        dec     esi
        cmp     esi, 0
        je      callClear

    loopAgain:
        loop    show

    jmp     endshow

    callClear:
        mov     esi, 10
        call    CrLf
        jmp     loopAgain

    endshow:
        pop     ebp
        ret     12

displayList ENDP

END main
```

*UPDATE*
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it exactly 130?  If you're truncating to bytes somewhere, 127 is the largest signed byte, and 128 or higher could "look like" a negative number.  When your code faults, what values are in registers?  Is the base in EDI right, and is the index in EDX in range?  Does it fault on the first iteration, or after looping off the end of the array for some reason?

Comment: If I enter in 130, then the program prints out an array of 130 random numbers. It then prints out the same array but is sorted from largest to smallest. If I enter in 131, the program crashes after the unsorted array prints out on the screen. I will post a screenshot  of the register values.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you after you've stepped through to see what happens? The debugger should also tell you if an instruction is accessing a bad address.

Comment: When it enters secondLoop, it gets stuck for a bit, then stops the program and throws an exception

Comment: `0x0040a000` is the start of a new page, so probably you just looped way too far.  Your EDX value at that point is way higher than 130.  Your bug probably causes you to access memory beyond the end of the array even with smaller numbers, but you only detect the bug with `130` or higher that reaches an unmapped page.  So probably you can single-step for small inputs and find out where you loop too many times.

Comment: I am new to Visual studio so what do you mean by single step for small input? and how do you determine the number loops?

Comment: In the debugger, set a breakpoint somewhere in your function.  Then use the button or keyboard shortcut to step by one instruction.  You can go through your program one instruction at a time, following how the CPU executes it.

Comment: I can't seem to find the problem... This is frustrating. I just removed one 
"inc" and now the highest number I can enter is 131.

Comment: You should remove `count           DWORD   11` from your `.data` section.  You never use it, just using registers to keep track of your array size.  (That's a good thing.)  Having it exist made me wonder if you overwrote it if you go off the end of the array, but not it turns out you don't use it at all.

Comment: Thank you I just deleted it. However, that did not change the error in the printout.

Comment: Of course it didn't.  It's just a red herring for future readers that want to look over you code, that's why I suggested you remove it.  And BTW, editing your question to remove the bugs that answers point out creates a moving target and invalidates the existing answer.  Don't do that.  If your program still has other bugs, then the question wasn't a [mcve] of a single bug, and unlikely to be helpful to future readers with the same problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the advice. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318690/i-am-getting-an-unusual-output-every-time-i-enter-a-number-greater-than-130-into

Here is the link to the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your registers, you'll see that `edx` is `0fA4h`, which is larger than it should be at the line it crashes on.  `ecx` is a negative number.  This is a clue that your loop is executing after it should have stopped.

The problem is that the `greater` branch will fall thru to the `lesser` branch.  This will decrement `ecx` again, causing it to go negative and your loop will just keep running until you get the access violation.

The quick fix is to put an unconditional `jmp` after the `loop` instruction under the `greater` label.

A better fix is to combine the tails of the loops into a simpler conditional:

```
    cmp     esi, [edi + (eax * 4)] ; compare array[j] and array[i]
    jle     lesser
    mov     eax, edx
lesser:
    inc     edx
    loop    secondLoop
```

Comment: Or a much better fix is to simplify and just `jng` over  `mov  eax, edx`.  No "else" is needed because the rest of the loop tail is common.

Comment: But where will it jump to?

Comment: @AeijanB In the original code, you'd jump to the `push edx` after the `loop` instruction in the `lesser` block, but I've updated my answer to include a better solution that avoids the duplicated code.

Comment: After I implemented your code, I stopped getting the exception error. However, when I entered a number higher than 130, I got this weird print out. I will post it above

Comment: @AeijanB You should ask a new question rather than modifying an existing question (since that modification invalidates the answers that have already been added).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56318690/i-am-getting-an-unusual-output-every-time-i-enter-a-number-greater-than-130-into 

I have never used StackOverFlow before so thank you for the advice. The link above leads to the new question.