# Random number array sorted with Selection Sort -- garbage characters output for size > 130

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

My program takes user input (integer between 10 and 200) and prints out the entered number of random numbers and stores them in an array. Then the array is sorted and printed out (SEE IMAGE BELOW). The median is of the numbers are also printed on the screen.

I have not been able to find the error. The program works perfectly for numbers less than or equal to 130, but not over 130.

```
TITLE Program5    (Program5.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

; (insert constant definitions here)
    MIN_INPUT = 10
    MAX_INPUT = 200
    LO_RANDOM = 100
    HI_RANDOM = 999

.data
request         DWORD   10
ask_user        BYTE    "How many numbers should be generated? [10 ... 200]: ", 0
error           BYTE    "Invalid input", 0

title_1         BYTE    "The unsorted random numbers: ", 0
title_2         BYTE    "The sorted list: ", 0
space           BYTE    "   ", 0
median          BYTE    "The median is: ", 0
temp            DWORD   0
list            DWORD   MAX_INPUT   DUP(?)

.code
main PROC

; (insert executable instructions here)
    call    randomize

    push    OFFSET request ;passed by reference
    call    getData

    call    CrLf

    push    request ; passed by value
    push    OFFSET list ; passed by reference
    call    fillArray

    push    OFFSET list
    push    request
    push    OFFSET title_1
    call    displaylist

    push    OFFSET list
    push    request
    call    sortList

    push    OFFSET list
    push    request
    call    displayMedian

    call    CrLf
    call    CrLf

    push    OFFSET list
    push    request
    push    OFFSET title_2
    call    displaylist

    exit    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

; (insert additional procedures here)
getData PROC

    push    ebp ;Set up stack frame
    mov     ebp, esp

    ;get an integer from user
    mov     ebx, [ebp+8]    ;get address of request into ebx

    L1:
        mov     edx, OFFSET ask_user
        call    WriteString
        call    ReadDec

        cmp     eax, MIN_INPUT
        jl      errorMessage
        cmp     eax, MAX_INPUT
        jg      errorMessage

        cmp     eax, MIN_INPUT
        jge     endThis
        cmp     eax, MAX_INPUT
        jle     endThis

    errorMessage:
        mov     edx, OFFSET error
        call    WriteString
        call    CrLf
        jmp     L1

    endThis:
        mov     [ebx], eax
        pop     ebp
        ret     4 ; remove four more bytes from the stack (after ret @)

getData ENDP

fillArray PROC
;include parameters - request (value), array (reference)
    ; MAJORITY OF THE FOLLOWING CODE WAS EXTRACTED FROM LECTURE 20 SLIDES
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp ;[ebp+4]
    mov     edi, [ebp+8] ; @list in edi
    mov     ecx, [ebp+12] ; value of request in ecx

    more:
        mov     eax, HI_RANDOM
        sub     eax, LO_RANDOM
        inc     eax
        call    RandomRange
        add     eax, LO_RANDOM

        mov     [edi], eax
        add     edi, 4
        loop    more

    endmore:
        pop     ebp
        ret     8
fillArray ENDP

sortList PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov     edi, [ebp+12]
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8]

    dec     ecx
    mov     ebx, 0

    firstLoop:
        mov     eax, ebx
        mov     edx, ebx
        inc     edx
        push    ecx
        mov     ecx, [ebp+8]

        secondLoop:
            mov     esi, [edi + (edx * 4)]
            cmp     esi, [edi + (eax * 4)]
            jle     lesser
            mov     eax, edx    
        lesser:
            inc     edx
            loop    secondLoop

        push    edx
        push    esi
        push    [edi + (ebx * 4)] ; array[k]
        push    [edi + (eax * 4)] ; array[i]
        call    exchangeElements
        pop     [edi + (eax * 4)]
        pop     [edi + (ebx * 4)]
        pop     esi
        pop     edx
        pop     ecx ; set the 
        inc     ebx ; increment k in the first loop
        loop    firstLoop

    pop     ebp
    ret     8

sortList ENDP

exchangeElements PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    mov     esi, [ebp+12] ; array[k]
    mov     edx, [ebp+8] ; array[i]
    mov     [ebp+8], esi
    mov     [ebp+12], edx
    pop     ebp
    ret     
exchangeElements ENDP

displayMedian PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp ;[ebp+4]
    mov     edi, [ebp+12] ; @list in edi
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8] ; value of request in ecx

    mov     eax, ecx
    mov     ebx, 2
    cdq
    div     ebx
    cmp     edx, 0
    je      isEven
    cmp     edx, 1
    je      isOdd

    ; https://github.com/TRMassey/CS271/blob/master/assignment5.asm
    isEven:
        ; find the higher number
        mov     ebx, 4
        mul     ebx
        add     edi, eax
        mov     edx, [edi]

        ; find the lower number
        mov     eax, edi
        sub     eax, 4
        mov     edi, eax
        mov     eax, [edi]

        ; add and divide them by 2
        add     eax, edx
        mov     edx, 0
        mov     ebx, 2
        cdq
        div     ebx

        ; print out the median value (rounded to the nearest int)
        call    CrLf
        call    CrLf
        mov     edx, OFFSET median
        call    WriteString
        call    WriteDec
        jmp     finish

    isOdd:
        mov     eax, [edi + (eax * 4)]
        call    CrLf
        call    CrLf
        mov     edx, OFFSET median
        call    WriteString
        call    WriteDec
        jmp     finish

    finish:
        pop ebp
        ret
displayMedian ENDP

displayList PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp ; [ebp+4]
    mov     ecx, [ebp+12] ; @request
    mov     edi, [ebp+16] ; @list
    mov     esi, 10

    mov     edx, [ebp+8] ; @title
    call    WriteString
    call    CrLf

    show:
        mov     eax, [edi]
        call    WriteDec
        mov     edx, OFFSET space
        call    WriteString
        add     edi, 4

        dec     esi
        cmp     esi, 0
        je      callClear

    loopAgain:
        loop    show

    jmp     endshow

    callClear:
        mov     esi, 10
        call    CrLf
        jmp     loopAgain

    endshow:
        pop     ebp
        ret     12

displayList ENDP

END main
```

Below is what my output currently looks like
[image]

Below is what I want my output to look like:
[image]

Comment: Distorted how?  Your output looks correctly sorted, in lexical string order(!!?!), not in integer order, which is weird but presumably on purpose.  This isn't a [mcve] because it doesn't show the output you *want*, or point out what's wrong with the current output.

Comment: Sorry if I am not giving enough information. I have updated my post and included a shortened version of my code.

Comment: Have you actually confirmed that it's only a problem with printing the output (like you said in the title), and the data is there in memory?  And your registers still have the values they're supposed to before calling the output function?

Comment: Why is the new screenshot totally different from the old one?  This one has garbage non-ASCII characters but the old one had numbers.  Does that happen sometimes depending on the random seed?

Comment: After much thought, the error could be that my sorting procedure is not properly swapping values.I am currently going through the code by hand to make sure my stack isn't the cause of the error. I think the displaying of the array is correct. Also, the random values that are displayed differ each time. Sometimes they are numbers and sometimes they are these unusual characters.

Comment: Don't make your title too generic, "my code has a problem" doesn't tell anyone anything.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for editing that for me.

Comment: Yup, the problem's in the sort.  Just before `secondLoop`, you set ecx to the number of elements (`ebp + 8`).  Then you only loop that many times to avoid walking over the end of the array.  But that supposes you are starting at index element 0.  If you start at (say) 60, then walk 200 elements, that's 60 too far.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd If I was out of bounds, wouldn't I get an exception thrown? The program finishes but the sort itself (I think there is a problem with the exchange procedure) is not working properly. On a side note, `ebp+8` is the user input on the stack.

Comment: In a high level language you'd get an out of bounds error as soon as you walk off the end of the array.  But in assembler, it might just give you whatever crap it finds there.  And since crap is what you're getting...

Comment: If I read that code right, isn't ebx the point at which you are starting your compares?  On the very first loop, that's zero, but that's not true for long.  If you reduced your "count" by your "start point", that should prevent you from ever walking too far.

Comment: Where do you recommend I do that subtraction?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't make any sense to do it before you read the value from ebp+8.  And if you do it after `secondLoop:`, you're going to be subtracting over and over again, and that's probably not what you want.  So between those two points sounds right.

Comment: sub     ecx, ebx ; 

ecx is the count, ebx is the starting point.

Is this how you do it? I subtracted the starting point (ebx) from the total count (ecx)

Comment: No, that's not where I'm referring to.  Right above `secondLoop` you load the value into ecx (`mov ecx, [ebp+8]`).  If you are processing 200 elements, that would set ecx to 200.  But you don't (always) want it to be 200.  Not if you are starting at (say) 60.  So that's the point to make the adjustment.  If you set it down below (like you just said), it's just going to get overwritten when it loops back to `firstloop`.  And it *must* be before `secondLoop`.  Oops!  You edited your comment.  Yes, that's how you do it, just not where.

Comment: My goodness... I think it did the trick!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Make sure you check carefully though, both the sort and the median.  I hope I've helped you understand 'why' it fixes it, not just 'how' to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and turn my comments into an Answer so we can close this question.

I believe the problem OP is experiencing comes from this code:

```
mov     ebx, 0

firstLoop:
    mov     eax, ebx
    mov     edx, ebx
    inc     edx
    push    ecx
    mov     ecx, [ebp+8]

    secondLoop:
        mov     esi, [edi + (edx * 4)]
        cmp     esi, [edi + (eax * 4)]
        jle     lesser
        mov     eax, edx    
    lesser:
        inc     edx
        loop    secondLoop
```

As you can see, ecx gets loaded from `[ebp+8]`.  This is where the user input regarding the number of entries is stored.  The code then walks over the array of generated random numbers located at edi.

The very first time this code is executed, ebx starts at 0.  So it safely walks the (say) 200 entries in the list.

However, on subsequent passes, ebx can be larger than 0.  But, ecx is still 200.  So we're still going to walk 200 entries, but we are no longer starting at index zero.

Which means, we're reading/writing past the end of the allocated space.  Which is why the output is junk.

The reason this seems to work for smaller numbers of entries is that the space for the list is pre-allocated (and apparently zero filled?).  Since the sort is 'descending,' the zeros all look like they don't need to be moved.

While I haven't traced thru all the ins and outs of the sort, at a minimum this is going to be a problem.

A simple fix of adding `sub ecx, ebx` right after `mov ecx, [ebp+8]` seems to resolve the problem.